# time stamp as input variable for regression (feature extraction)

Tags: regression, time-series, data-transformation, feature-engineering

I am working on web logs and have a time-stamp variable in the format dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss.

I have earlier worked on date variable and found that best way to extract feature from date is to create dummy variables based on day-of-week month-of-the-year etc. Not sure how to deal with hourly data, and for that matter time-stamp data.

Any idea how to extract feature or usable information from time-stamp for predicting sales?

Comment: Intuitively, e.g. hour-of-day and similar abstractions, or some categories ("morning", "noon", ...) could make sense (you might need to deal with different time zones). For the latter, using domain knowledge about what will influence your sales would make sense (e.g. sales might go up after people stop working and do some shopping, so more fine grained categories might make sense).

Comment: @geekoverdose Thanks! i was anticipating if there is any better way, than creating dummy variables for different hours. This seems a reasonable solution though.